# Datasource for regression model prediction based on micro/macro economic factors

Tags: data-request

I am trying to work using Amazon machine learning, but the data set that I have is small. The model I want to build is for regression based predictions and the domain I am aiming for the data set to belong is financial, say stock price prediction, price and demand prediction based on macro/micro economic factor.

i am looking for a data set that contains the factor that lead to a particular value; say for example- i want to predict the value of 1 unit of polyster after 1 year, the factors over which the yarn price depends are say - figures of IIP , prices of crude oil, GDP of country, Inflation etc .. so i want a data set that contains the quotes of these factors too on which the final price depends.

The reason why i am not arranging the data by my self is because i dont know all the factors that contribute to a certain predictive price.so i was thinking if some expert have already given the data set for a particular problem class then it can be used for my purpose.